# org-mode in emacs, press <RET> have no effect

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying out org-mode in emacs. Strangely, after hooking `org-mode` to `text-mode`, whenever I press `<RET>` key on headlines, the mini-buffer shows

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

And nothing happens. Similar things happen to normal text region after I use `<alt>-q` for column filling.

This issue do no present if I don't hook it to `text-mode` and only manually invoke it after opening a file.

What could be causing the issue? Is there any way to debug it?

Comment: `text-mode` and `org-mode` are two distinct `major-mode` that are designed to work independently.  You should choose one or the other.  If you want `org-mode`, type `M-x org-mode`.  If you want `text-mode`, type `M-x text-mode`.  Do *not* attempt to hook the two `major-mode` together.  If you want to achieve certain behavior in a particular `major-mode`, then those behavioral modifications may be added to a `major-mode` hook.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks, I partially solved the problem by linking some of the suffix to org-mode. But is there a way to set the default text mode to org-mode? Because frankly, text-mode's functionality is just like a subset of org-mode, isn't it?

Comment: When you get more advanced, you can create your own major-mode.  In the meantime, I suggest you pick a particular feature that is lacking/annoying in `org-mode` and figure out how to add/disable that feature.  For example, maybe you don't like how shift-left works when your cursor is at a particular location -- you may decide to disable that behavior in `org-mode`.  You need to handle each issue one at a time.  Be prepared to invest a substantial amount of time customizing Emacs to your precise needs.